# Transcoding from DVD to MP4 and intentionally skip frames in the middle

Tags: dvd, mplayer, transcode

I have a DVD that I'd like to transcode from a DVD format to MP4 so I can play it on my iPad. Normally this is trivially easy as I could use Handbrake. But this has an interesting twist.

Around thirty minutes into the video there is a small glitch on the DVD. This glitch causes some minor distortion when played on a physical DVD player, but software DVD players and transcoders see this and have problems. This means that my 13 year old Sony DVD player can play the DVD, but if I try to play it in VLC, Windows Media Center, etc, when it hits the glitch the DVD freezes. Handbrake will act like it is ripping at this point, but will hang at 100% and create a file that keeps on growing.

I can pinpoint down to the EXACT frames where the glitch exists. It's about 3 frames long and as near as I can tell it doesn't contain any I frames, only P frames. So, I'd like to tell whatever transcoder I end up using to transcode all of the DVD, but skip from frames 52134 to 52136. I can rip the entire DVD image and play it back using `mplayer` if I tell it to stop at frame 52134 and then restart mplayer and tell it start at frame 52136. This should get me part of the way as I can create two dumpstreams, but I can't figure out how to merge the .vob files or encode them together.